# GetCmp() is not working in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i'm using `getCmp('componentid').hide();`
its not working.

```
if (flag_in == 1) {
    console.log('inside if of hide'); 
    Ext.getCmp('inboxQueueId').hide();                                    

    var el = btn.el;  
    Ext.getCmp('inbox_hide').setIconCls('show');                              
    flag_in = 0;
    Ext.getCmp('queueViewPanel').setWidth('100%');

} else {
      console.log('inside else of hide'); 
   Ext.getCmp('inboxQueueId').show();                               

  var element = btn.element;
  Ext.getCmp('inbox_hide').setIconCls('hide');

 flag_in = 1;
 Ext.getCmp('queueViewPanel').setWidth('70%');
 }
```

its coming inside if but `Ext.getCmp('inboxQueueId').hide()` is not working.
And its not giving error.
Please help me.

Comment: How you define object with id "inboxQueueId"?

Comment: inboxQueueId is the Id of the panel which i want to hide.

Comment: if you test in Chrome try to write Ext.getCmp('inboxQueueId').hide();   in Chrome console. Test a little bit, or show me your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

`Ext.getCmp('inboxQueueId').hide('slide', false)`

Or something like this,

`Ext.getCmp('inboxQueueId').hide(false)`

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: for Ext.getCmp('inboxQueueId').hide('slide', false) its not giving error but not hiding left panel.

Comment: for Ext.getCmp('inboxQueueId').setVisible(false)  its giving error: has no method setVisible ().

Comment: i my application dulpicate id was present that why it was not working .i removed dulicate id its working fine now.